# Unable to enter text into a windows form

Tags: protractor

My site requires a file to be imported.  This is done through a button click and then a windows standard form to find the file on my desktop.  I'm struggling to get protractor to enter the desktop location.  I have it as a .sendkeys to the original button.click

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

var myPath = require('path');

```
it('tests the file upload functionality', function() {
  var fileToUpload = '../yourpath/yourfile.exe',
      absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

  element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);    
  element(by.id('uploadBtn')).click();
});
```

1. Use the path module to resolve the full path of the file.
2. Set the path to the input[type="file"] element.
3. Click on the upload button.

Note, It won't work under FF, in order to upload in FF, make the input field visible:

```
browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
  document.querySelectorAll('#inputElem')[0].style.display = 'inline';
  callback();
});

// Now upload should work
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);    
$('#uploadButton').click();
```

Comment: To add to your answer, you wouldnt need to click on the upload button again. Just submit the form behind the scenes